# Using app_offline with TFS2015 RM

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines, app-offline.htm

I am in the course of setting up continuous deployment to IIS using TFS 2015 RM and wanted to take an application offline before deployment. Upon little research have found good posts on achieving it through “app_offline.htm” file with following steps.

1. Creating an “app_offline.htm” file in the "root" of the website but with a different name (app_offline.htm_) to avoid debugging or related problems.
2. Before deployments, rename the file back to “app_offline” and place it in the destination web app.
3. Post deployment, we delete the file from destination web app.

Currently, I have included the “Windows Machine File Copy” task to copy build binaries along with “app_offline.htm_” to destination web app and “Delete Files” task to delete it post deployment.

Now, All I want to understand is how to rename the file back to app_offline.htm before deployment.
Help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do it:

1. Using PowerShell (e.g. [Rename-Item](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176940.aspx)) script through **PowerShell on Target Machines** (rename file that on remove machine) or **PowerShell** (rename file on build agent machine) step/task
2. Deploy web app through **WinRM-IIS Web App Deployment** step/task with **Take App Offline** option. (Install [IIS Web App Deployment Using WinRM](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.iiswebapp) extension)
3. Re-copy all files (include app_offline.html) to target machine through **Windows Machine File Copy** with **Clean Target** option

Comment: With 2nd way, i had a quick question. I have noticed that extension  requires binaries to be packaged and then we can refer those in the extension. In such case, do we need to include another task to unzip?

Comment: This task does not unzip the binaries, moreover as i had added these MS build arguments to zip the binaries "/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)"
I get this lengthy file path (Project.zip\Content\E_C\WebWork\1\s\Dev\ProviderGeoSearch\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Allbinaries) once I open the zip file.
Tried Copy Publish Artifact task with minimatch **\PackageTmp to get contents only from PackageTmp folder in that lengthy path,It copies but not as zip file now

Comment: @Sam You don't need to worry about the structure, it won't keep the structure after app be deployed to the IIS. Also, the task 'unzip' the package files. On the other hand, there are many extensions that can zip or unzip the files. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=zip&target=VSTS&sortBy=Relevance

Answer (score 0):

I didn't like any of the accepted answer's solutions.  Mainly because they all involve `WinRM` which requires ports to be opened on the server, and I just don't want to talk to the infrastructure guy as opening ports makes him stressed.

Also if you use the `clean` option on the `Copy Files task` it does leave zero files in the `Inetpub` folder for just a second - any requests at that moment will 404 or generally blow up.

I set 3 `Copy Files tasks` functions in my build pipeline.

1. To copy an `app_offline.htm` into the folder.
2. To do the original build copy with all the main website files
3. To copy a `app_offline.htm` with zero bytes over the top of the first one.

Then have a service running on the server - can do a `filewatcher` or I just polled it, but when that file is zero bytes - bin it.

Very frustrating that the `msbuild agent.exe` on the server can't do anything but "copy files"